# How can I load only changed data in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have weekly user login data for a program. I need to set up my query to only append rows for the people who logged in this week. The query is pulled from a folder containing each week's export in a separate csv file.

Example of files with pull date, user name, and last login:

*Pull date: 2019-08-09*
Mufasa    08-08
Simba     08-08
Nala       08-07
Timon    07-15
Pumba    06-03

*Pull date: 2019-08-16*
Mufasa    08-14
Simba     08-13
Nala       08-12
Timon     07-15
Pumba    06-03

*Pull date: 2019-08-23*
Mufasa    08-23
Simba     08-13
Nala       08-12
Timon    07-15
Pumba    06-03

**What I want to see in PowerBI is this:**
Mufasa    08-08
Mufasa    08-14
Mufasa    08-23
Simba     08-08
Simba     08-13
Nala       08-07
Nala       08-12
Timon    07-15
Pumba    06-03

I don't think I want incremental refresh, but I'm willing to learn more. I want my appended query to only have the data indicated, not just an abbreviated refresh. I may be misunderstanding how incremental refresh works, though.

Would a parameter on last login work, and if so, how would I set that up?

Comment: Could you just left join the names/IDs from the most recent file with those in all the other files?

Comment: I would still need to filter before the left join. Every file has every person who ever logged in, while I only want the people who have logged in this past week (without overwriting their past data).

Comment: Looking at your expected output again, I think I misunderstood at first. Your output looks like it's just deduped - is this correct? If so, you could just use `Table.Distinct`.